# How can I disable/suppress the warning sound played whenever I am building and have warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

My question today is right to the point. So whenever I build my project or my solution and there is a warning about anything such as a deprecated method, visual studio plays an annoying warning sound and I don't know how to disable the warning sound from being played. I know how to set it so that none of the warnings show up, but the warning sound still plays. Please, if anybody reading my question knows how to disable the warning sound played when visual studio encounters a warning while building projects, I would greatly appreciate your answers or advice. By the way, for reference, I am using C++ in Visual Studio 2010. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's in Windows' sound theme control panel.

Comment: `My question today is right to the point.` Deliberate irony?

Answer (score -4):

Unplug your loudspeaker system from the sound output jack, turn the volume down to zero or just unplug your loudspeaker system from the mains power.  All of these methods have been tested and work well.