# disable error sounds visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, audio

Looked for a solution but I only found 1 answer which is semi good- it is disabling the system sounds...

What I want is to disable the annoying error sounds that visual studio makes when there are errors on build. I use headphones and it is really annoying. I want to disable it, WITHOUT disabling/modifying the windows' system sounds in the control panel... is it possible??

([similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292939/how-can-i-disable-suppress-the-warning-sound-played-whenever-i-am-building-and-h) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution 1: Set the sound to none**

It's in `Control Panel -> Sound`. Look for `Microsoft Visual Studio`, set the sound for `Build Failed` to `(None)`.

[image]

**Solution 2: Registry**

1. Open `Registry Editor`
2. Go to the following keys and delete their values: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\devenv\VS_BuildFailed\.current`
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\devenv\VS_BuildFailed\.Modified`
   [image]

**Solution 3: Adjust the sound volume of Visual Studio**

1. Make sure you have assigned sound for items in `Microsoft Visual Studio` in `Control Panel -> Sound`. It can be `Breakpoint Hit`, `Build Canceled`, `Build Failed` or `Build Succeed`.
2. Purposely hit a break point or build successfully or whatever, just to force Visual Studio to make a sound. This step is required, otherwise you won't see volume control for Visual Studio in step 5.
3. Click the speaker icon on the tray area of the taskbar.
4. Click `Mixer` in the popup window.

[image]

5. You will see something like the below. Adjust the volume for `Microsoft Visual Studio`. You can also mute just Visual Studio by clicking the speaker icon below it.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks- but there are all on none... 
I believe the sound is from the Windows sounds the "Exclamation".

Comment: @ZivWeissman, sometimes the Sound in Control Panel has two parts of `Microsoft Visual Studio`, make sure they are all `(None)`. Or you can try the alternative solution in the updated answer.

Comment: @ZivWeissman: added another solution, remove the sound directly through registry :)

Comment: Man thanks for your time, and the images and the solutions!! but i'm afraid none of them are valid in this case XD.
The sound even in registry is null. 
I tried the trick with the mixer, but the "Microsoft Visual Studio" does not appear. When the sound is hit I see "System Sounds" is activated.

In the control panel--> if I turn off the sound for Exclamation, I won't have this error sound... but I eliminate all Exclamation sounds... (if it is the only solution I will do it)

Comment: @ZivWeissman, what's the sound you hear if you set `Build Failed` to a sound other than Exclamation? If you still hear Exclamation, then the sound should be from something else, maybe a Visual Studio Addin, extension, or something in your Build Event.

Comment: @ZivWeissman, you may find which program is making the sound by using [Process Monitor](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-application-making-sounds-in-background/)

Comment: Ok.. I looked, the app that's doing the sound is "taskhost.exe" --> which is in windows/system32... 
Basically what is doing the noise is windows popup window that visual studio is pooping.... (Title of the popup is "Microsoft Visual Studio")

Comment: @ZivWeissman, So this is not the sound from Build Failed event. It really is the Exclamation sound from a message box having an exclamation mark on it :) ! You either eliminate the source (program/command) that shows this message box, or make the `Exclamation` entry in `Control Panel -> Sound` to `(None)`. What's the message in the message box? It's a hint of what causes it.

Comment: Thanks... I gave up on this. I just put the Exclamation to none and that's it... :/ the message box comes from visual studio. The title of it is "Microsoft Visual Studio"... the text is something about dll that can't be replaced because it is locked or something like that. (happens several times each time i build the project).

Thanks for help... I gave up.

Comment: Muting system sounds in desktop(tray icon)  worked for me